# Removing FLEXnet Connect Update Manager

Tags: uninstall, spyware, bloatware

Do you know how can I remove this unwanted software? Status line says copyright Acresso Software and or InstallShield. From the folder in ProgramData I understand it is version 11.

Comment: So a normal uninstall doesn't work?

Comment: @Karan: There is no uninstall. Surely, it came as an undesired gift of some other application. Who knows which one....

Comment: I'm guessing it came with some Adobe (Creative Suite?) software. I'm not sure if it's safe to remove this; the software might stop functioning as it's part of some licensing system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One simple solution to safely uninstall FlexNet Software Update manager by using this tool:
Download uninstaller from: http://support.installshield.com/kb/files/Q112918/SoftwareManagerUninstall.exe
IMPORTANT: Run as admin!

It works clean and perfect: succes!

Comment: More details here [flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/HOWTO/Q111006](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/HOWTO/Q111006)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't crapware.

That piece of software is a feature of [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com/) - a popular installer system; it has also this kind of updater service that developers may use to deliver updates to their application. Its presence doesn't hurt, but if you really want to uninstall it you'll need to remove the software it came with, look for anything that uses InstallShield to install itself.

Comment: It kind of is crapware, in at least some circumstances. When it is installed along with the Nuance PaperPort product that is installed with Brother printer drivers, for instance, it is allegedly there to check for software updates, but effectively only ever pesters you, with an annoying popup, to upgrade the free limited edition of PaperPort that installs with your printer driver to the full paid version of PaperPort.